# Find Computer Model and Store in a Text File

Tags: vbscript

I need a bit of help. This script is meant to find the computer model and put it in a 
text file. It doesn't seem to be working. There are no errors or anything, so I'm slightly stuck. Any help would be great as I'm new to VBScript.

```
Class classname

    dim objFSO  
    dim objFOLDER 
    dim objFile 
    dim strDir 
    dim strFile 

    Sub subname1()
        strComputer = "." 
        Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
        Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
            "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem",,48) 

        'For loop to cycle through each result
        For Each objItem in colItems
            'Calling the other sub ***just an example*** place where needed.
            Subname2()
            objModel = objItem.Model
            'enable only when trying to obtain exact model number
            Wscript.Echo objModel
        next
    End Sub

    'New Sub that will be called by first sub
     Sub Subname2()
        Explicit
        strDir = "c:\model"
        strFile = objModel
        set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        set objFOLDER = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDir)
        set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strDir & strFile)

        Wscript.Quit
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are we to assume that you're creating an instance of this class and then calling the `subname1()` method? What's with the `Explicit` keyword by itself in `Subname2()`? How is `Subname2()` supposed to know what `objModel` is?

Comment: Why do you quit the script in `Subname2()`?

Comment: im trying to find the model of the laptop in Subname 1 then trying to pass it to the Subname 2

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really said what you want to put in the file you create, but you're not actually passing anything to subname2, and there are a lot of unnecessary variables scoped to the class which is quite confusing. This should create a text file named after the PC model in `c:\model` provided the model doesn't have any invalid characters in it:

```
Class classname


    Sub subname1()
        dim wmi
        dim colItems
        dim objItem

        Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") 
        Set colItems = wmi.ExecQuery( _
            "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem",,48) 

        'For loop to cycle through each result
        For Each objItem in colItems
            'Calling the other sub ***just an example*** place where needed.
            Subname2(objItem.Model)
        next
    End Sub

    'New Sub that will be called by first sub
     Sub Subname2(model)
        dim fso
        dim ofile

        set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        fso.CreateFolder("c:\model\")
        set ofile = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\model\" & model & ".txt")
        ofile.close
        Wscript.Quit
    End Sub
End Class
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes thank you sorry for been unclear cant always get down whats in my head on paper sorry